# Positioning signature on left in letter

Tags: letters, newlfm

I have this letter template, I found online.

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter]{newlfm}
\usepackage{charter}

\widowpenalty=1000
\clubpenalty=1000

\newlfmP{headermarginskip=15pt}
\newlfmP{sigsize=25pt}
\newlfmP{dateskipafter=25pt}
\newlfmP{addrfromphone}
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\PhrPhone{Phone}
\PhrEmail{Email}

\namefrom{James Bond}

\addrfrom{Privet Drive}
\phonefrom{111-333-4422}
\emailfrom{abc@mnop.com}

\addrto{XYZ Inc.}

\greetto{To Whom It May Concern,}
\closeline{Sincerely,}

\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}

\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

For some reason, I cannot get the `\namefrom` and `\closeline` to left indent. It keeps positioning on the right. I tried `\flushright` and `\flushleft`

Comment: What do you mean left indent? Do you mean left align? That is, you want `\namefrom` and `\closeline` to be aligned to the left of the page?

Comment: Yes, I mean left align.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `sigleft` class option:

```
\documentclass[11pt,stdletter,sigleft]{newlfm}
```