# Tex Cover Letter Doesn't Display "Sincerely, My Name"

Tags: spacing, packages, newlfm

I'm using the [cover letter example](http://www.matthewjmiller.net/files/cover_letters/cover_example.tex) from this website: http://www.matthewjmiller.net/howtos/customized-cover-letter-scripts/

What it should look like and the source of the tex is on that website, I can't link to more than 2 links without having reputation, so if you could check the website, that would be amazing.

Here is what I come out with:

[image]

1. FIXED: It went to the other page: (There is no "Sincerely, My Name") #1 is solved.
2. FIXED: I replaced a line with: "\newlfmP{headermarginskip=-40pt}" There is a huge space between the company letterhead and the date
3. The date is not in line with the address.

How do I fix these?

Comment: For 1. [Positioning signature on left in letter](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13167/15717). For 3.[newlfm date annoyance](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55005/15717). click on the tag `newlfm`, you will find questions related to this letter class. BTW, i have included tag `newlfm` to your question which is suited for your question.

Comment: Thanks. For #1 The problem was that there was no Sincerely, My Name. It was inexistant. Take a look at my imgur link. There is no Sincerely, My Name. For #3, I tried that, It adds a date properly alligned, but the original date that is stuck to the right of the page is also still there.

Comment: Did you try going through and running the example shown by Gonzalo Medina in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55005/15717. "Sincerely" comes from `\closeline{Sincerely,}` in your source file. Your example compiled well on `Texlive 2012` without the  problems mentioned above. I dont have `miktex`. Lets see for other comments.

Comment: #1 is solved, but the newlfm date is still there. I some of the text from the example shown by Gonzalo Medina and I got this: http://imgur.com/djcRy I think it has something to do with the packages? The date fixes itself, but the other date remains there.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Answer (score 5):

1. The letter ending rolls over to a subsequent page. If you wish it to remain on a single page, then you need to reduce the content you currently have.
2. The distance between the header and the start of the address block is consumed by lengths like `\headermarginskip`, `\datebeforeskip` and `\dateafterskip`. Setting any one of these to an appropriate negative value will push up the content.
3. The date in [`newlfm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm) is set using `\dateset`. I would suggest, if you plan on requiring an alignment with the "from" address, to include the date there using `\today\\[<len>]` (where you specify an appropriate length `<len>` to separate the date from the address, if needed) and use `\dateset{}` (to remove the traditional date setting.

---

On a related note, you can also obtain the formatting you want without sticking to structure provided by `newlfm`. Here's a take on such a document structure, written in the `article` class:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url,charter,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{url,charter,graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{\jot}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-a} \par
\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}

\null\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  \today \\[\jot]
    439 Coordinated Science Laboratory \\
    1308 West Main Street \\
    Urbana, IL 61801 \\
  Phone: 217-244-6024 \\
  Email: mjmille2@uiuc.edu
\end{tabular}  

\bigskip\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Faculty Search Committee \\
  Department of Computer Science \\
  Clemson University \\
  Clemson, SC 29634-0974
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

To Whom It May Concern,

\medskip

I am writing to apply for the position of assistant
professor in Clemson University's Computer Science Department. I plan to receive my
Ph.D.\ degree from the University of Illinois at
Urbana-Champaign in Summer of~2006. My adviser is
Prof.\ Nitin H.\ Vaidya, and my general areas of interest
include wireless and sensor network performance and security.
 Having many friends and family in the area, I would be
most enthused to return to the South permanently by accepting
a position at your institution.

In my graduate work, I focus on the design of
energy-efficient protocols and secure key distribution.
More specifically, I have explored various techniques at
multiple layers of the network stack to effectively reduce
the energy consumption of wireless communication. In security,
my work was the first to propose leveraging channel diversity
for sensor network key distribution. My research appears in 
the \textit{IEEE Transactions on Mobile Computing} journal as
well as \textit{Infocom~2006} and \textit{ICDCS~2005},
prestigious conferences in the areas of networking and distributed
systems, respectively.

Enclosed is my curriculum vitae (including a list of
publications), contact information for my references, a research
statement, and a teaching statement. All of my publications and
presentations are available at:

\url{http://www.crhc.uiuc.edu/~mjmille2/publications/}

Please let me know if there are any other materials
or information that will assist you in processing my application.

Thank you for your consideration. I look forward to
hearing from you.

\bigskip

\null\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Sincerely, \\[5\normalbaselineskip]
  Matthew J.\ Miller
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I find the readability of the code to be easier. The sequence of input matches the output, rather than a scattered preamble for specifying content that makes its way into the start/end of the `newlfm` environment. There is, of course, also [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), which provides a similar layout.

If you wish to add a personalized signature to your letter, consider reading [Adding a signature on an online job application](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32911/5764).

Comment: Great Reply! I will look into the article class. I want to just finish one cover letter with the current class. What do I substitute for the [<len>] in the "\today\\[<len>]". I just want it to match up. I tried 1pt, or 1, or true, with, without the brackets, nothing works, it won't typeset.

Comment: @piratepartypumpkin: You see how I used `\today\\[\jot]`? `\jot` is `3pt`. Perhaps you want to use something bigger, like `.5\normalbaselineskip` which will be half of a usual line of text. See [What are the possible dimensions / sizes / units LaTeX understands?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41370/5764)